KMP Decompose: Multiple retainedcomponents error due to an already registered key Android app crash
I am setting up navigation for my KMP shared UI project using Decompose library. I will post all code snippets in the link below.
Basic details :
RootComponent->
SplashScreen,LoginScreen,DashBoardScreen
DashBoardScreen->DashBoardRootComponent->
PlayListScreen,TrackListScreen
RootComponent and DashBoardRootComponent object is created on each OS entry point.
I want this flow.
I’ve raised an issue on the Decompose GitHub page, and all the details are provided there
class RootComponent(componentContext: ComponentContext) : ComponentContext by componentContext {
    private val navigation = StackNavigation<Configuration>()

    val childStack = childStack(
        key = "mainRoot",
        source = navigation,
        serializer = Configuration.serializer(),
        initialConfiguration = Configuration.SplashActivity,
        handleBackButton = true,
        childFactory = ::createRootChild
    )

    private fun createRootChild(
        configuration: Configuration, context: ComponentContext
    ): Child {
        return when (configuration) {
            is Configuration.SplashActivity -> Child.SplashActivity(
                SplashComponent(contextComponent = context, onTimerComplete = {
                    navigation.pushNew(Configuration.LoginActivity)
                })
            )

            is Configuration.LoginActivity -> Child.LoginActivity(
                LoginComponent(componentContext = context, onLogin = {
                    navigation.pushNew(Configuration.DashboardActivity)
                })
            )

            is Configuration.DashboardActivity -> Child.DashboardActivity(DashboardComponent(context))
        }
    }

    sealed class Child {
        data class SplashActivity(val component: SplashComponent) : Child()
        data class LoginActivity(val component: LoginComponent) : Child()
        data class DashboardActivity(val component: DashboardComponent) : Child()
    }

    @Serializable
    sealed class Configuration {
        @Serializable
        data object SplashActivity : Configuration()

        @Serializable
        data object LoginActivity : Configuration()

        @Serializable
        data object DashboardActivity : Configuration()
    }
}

Here my DashBoardRootComponent class
class DashBoardRootComponent(componentContext: ComponentContext) :
    ComponentContext by componentContext {
    private val navigation = StackNavigation<Configuration>()

    val childStack = childStack(
        key = "dashBoardRoot",
        source = navigation,
        serializer = Configuration.serializer(),
        initialConfiguration = Configuration.PlayListActivity,
        handleBackButton = true,
        childFactory = ::createDashBoardChild
    )

    private fun createDashBoardChild(
        configuration: Configuration, context: ComponentContext
    ): Child {
        return when (configuration) {
            is Configuration.PlayListActivity -> Child.PlayListActivity(
                PlayListComponent(componentContext = context, onPlayListClick = {
                    navigation.pushNew(Configuration.TrackListActivity)
                })
            )

            is Configuration.TrackListActivity -> Child.TrackListActivity(TrackListComponent(componentContext = context,
                onTrackListClick = {
                },
                onBackPress = {
                    navigation.pop()
                }))
        }
    }

    sealed class Child {
        data class PlayListActivity(val component: PlayListComponent) : Child()
        data class TrackListActivity(val component: TrackListComponent) : Child()
//        data class DashboardActivity(val component: DashboardComponent) : Child()
    }

    @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
    sealed class Configuration {
        @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
        data object PlayListActivity : Configuration()

        @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
        data object TrackListActivity : Configuration()
    }

}

My App Component
@Composable
@Preview
fun App(root: RootComponent, dashBoardRoot: DashBoardRootComponent) {
    MaterialTheme {
        val childStack by root.childStack.subscribeAsState()
        Children(
            stack = childStack,
            animation = stackAnimation(slide()),
            content = { child ->
                when (val instance = child.instance) {
                    is RootComponent.Child.SplashActivity -> Splash(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.LoginActivity -> Login(instance.component)
                    is RootComponent.Child.DashboardActivity -> Dashboard(
                        instance.component,
                        dashBoardRootComponent = dashBoardRoot
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

For Android MainActivity 1st Try
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val rootF = retainedComponent {
            RootComponent(it)
        }
        val dashF = retainedComponent {
            DashBoardRootComponent(it)
        }
        setContent {
            App(rootF, dashF)
        }
    }
}

Logcat :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.neonmusic.app, PID: 3633
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.neonmusic.app/com.neonmusic.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
    at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.kt:110)
    at com.arkivanov.essenty.statekeeper.AndroidExtKt.StateKeeper(AndroidExt.kt:31)
    at com.arkivanov.essenty.statekeeper.AndroidExtKt.stateKeeper(AndroidExt.kt:54)
    at com.arkivanov.decompose.RetainedComponentKt.retainedComponent(RetainedComponent.kt:101)
    at com.arkivanov.decompose.RetainedComponentKt.retainedComponent(RetainedComponent.kt:52)
    at com.arkivanov.decompose.RetainedComponentKt.retainedComponent$default(RetainedComponent.kt:45)
    at com.neonmusic.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)  

For Android MainActivity 2nd Try from chatGpt reference
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val root = retainedComponentWithKey(key = "RootComponent_mainRoot") {
            RootComponent(it)
        }
        val dashBoardRoot = retainedComponentWithKey(key = "DashBoardRootComponent_dashBoardRoot") {
            DashBoardRootComponent(it)
        }

        setContent {
            App(root.first, dashBoardRoot.first)
        }
    }

    private fun <T : Any> retainedComponentWithKey(
        key: String,
        factory: (ComponentContext) -> T
    ): Pair<T, String> {
        val component = retainedComponent(key = key, handleBackButton = true, factory = factory)
        return component to key
    }
}

Logcat :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.neonmusic.app, PID: 3248
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.neonmusic.app/com.neonmusic.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
    at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.kt:110)
    at com.arkivanov.essenty.statekeeper.AndroidExtKt.StateKeeper(AndroidExt.kt:31)
    at com.arkivanov.essenty.statekeeper.AndroidExtKt.stateKeeper(AndroidExt.kt:54)
    at com.arkivanov.decompose.RetainedComponentKt.retainedComponent(RetainedComponent.kt:101)
    at com.arkivanov.decompose.RetainedComponentKt.retainedComponent(RetainedComponent.kt:52)
    at com.arkivanov.decompose.RetainedComponentKt.retainedComponent$default(RetainedComponent.kt:45)
    at com.neonmusic.app.MainActivity.retainedComponentWithKey(MainActivity.kt:33)
    at com.neonmusic.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)  

I am facing this issue only for android
Do code for desktop also but it will working fine.
Here Desktop entry point
fun main() = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        title = "neon-music-kmp",
    ) {
        val root = remember { RootComponent(DefaultComponentContext(LifecycleRegistry())) }
        val dashBoardRoot = remember { DashBoardRootComponent(DefaultComponentContext(LifecycleRegistry())) }
        App(root, dashBoardRoot)
    }
}

Can any one explain me where i need to give unique key for android retainedComponent ?
Tell me if i am wrong in anything.

Thanks to the Decompose library owner for providing a quick response and saving my time. Here’s the code for the Android entry point to create two retainedComponent.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val (rootComponent, dashBoardRootComponent) = retainedComponent {
            RootComponent(it.childContext("root")) to DashBoardRootComponent(it.childContext("dash"))
        }
        setContent {
            App(rootComponent, dashBoardRootComponent)
        }
    }
}


Here link for original answer by owner. Solution
